# Gtk3 css applying class not working?

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3

**EXPLANATION AND WHAT I TRIED:**

I have this structure in my application:

```
GtkWindow
   GtkOverlay
      GtkBox
         GtkGrid
            GtkButton
```

when I try to apply this :

```
    GtkButton{
     background-color:blue;
}
```

button has default style applied from `.button` class

I tried

```
GtkWindow GtkOverlay GtkBox GtkGrid GtkButton
{
background-color:blue;
}
```

it's not working too

I tried to use !important but I guess Gtk engine doesn't support it.

**Q:Is there any way to force class on some widgets or to give it a higher priority?**

Thank is advance

Comment: applying it inline (inline styling) should work, as it has a higher precedence than the class def. obviously, this should only be used if you don't have access to that button class. Otherwise, placing it at the bototm of your style sheet (below the styling) will also override it. another option would be to use javascript, and change it this way if dynamically added

Comment: @jbutler483 this is Gtk not HTML

Comment: My bad, I saw css and presumed gtk was a plugin of some sort. But the *placing it at the bototm of your style sheet (below the styling) will also override it.* should still work as that's how **all** css styling works

Comment: I tried it too but it's not working, don't know why I pressume gtk default theming engine is applying it's own css after mine

Comment: unfortunately I haven't any experience with Gtk, only css. Another way (in css, that is), is to define a styling that is **more specific** than one already set, and *that shhould* override it

Comment: What kind of blue button do you want? [This one?](http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/files/2014/03/gedit-messagedialog.png) Or just a generic blue button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the properties for one widget, just use CSS Selector #id.

For example (I use GLADE to build the UI so not sure how to do it in code), I have a button on my about tab that I changed for this test, I gave it the #id of update (widget name in glade) and my css looks like this (As you didn't specify a language, the following is 64bit Assembly using NASM on Linux):

```
szAboutCSS              db 'GtkEventBox#abouttab{'
                        db 'background-color: black;'
                        db 'color: white;'
                        db 'font: bold;}'

                        db 'GtkButton#update{'
                        db 'font: normal;'
                        db 'color: red;'
                        db 'background: blue;}'

                        db 'GtkLabel#version{'
                        db 'color: #FF0000;'
                        db 'font-size: 10px}', 0
```

and while I am getting all of the objects I need from the UI file and before I call `gtk_widget_show_all` I call this function to apply the css to my about tab:

```
SetAboutColor:
    sub     rsp, 8 

%define _Provider   [rsp]

    call    gtk_css_provider_new
    mov     _Provider, rax

    call    gdk_display_get_default

    mov     rdi, rax
    call    gdk_display_get_default_screen

    mov     rdx, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
    mov     rsi, _Provider
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen

    mov     rcx, NULL
    mov     rdx, -1
    mov     rsi, szAboutCSS
    mov     rdi, _Provider
    call    gtk_css_provider_load_from_data

    mov     rdi, _Provider
    call    g_object_unref

    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

And the outcome:
[image]